# React input elements rendering in wrong order on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of inputs with an empty input at the end.

If a user types in this empty input, the state is changed to reflect this, and a new blank input is added to the end.

If the user deletes the value in the input at the end (not the blank one), this input is removed and we still have a blank input at the end.

The issue: There are at least 4 inputs (first 3 with values, last blank as expected). The user makes input 2 blank.

Expected result: Inputs are re-rendered in the new order (Input1, Input3, BlankInput)

Actual result: Inputs rendered in this order (Input 1, BlankInput, Input3)

Code:

```
type Props = {}

const InitialState = {
    data: [],
}

type State = typeof InitialState
export default class List extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    public state = InitialState
    componentDidMount() {
        var inputs = [];
        //Call API to get data
        getList().then((dataArray) => {
            inputs = JSON.parse(dataArray)
            this.setState({ data: inputs })
        });    
    }

    generateInput(input: any) {
        var listArray = input.config.order.split(',');
        listArray.push('');
        return listArray;
    }
    
    delaySaveOfList(e: React.ChangeEvent<any>, input: any, name: string) {
        var listArray = input.config.order.split(',')
        var arrTarget = Number(e.target.name);
        var inputLength = e.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll("#ListInput").length - 1
        if (e.target.value == "" && inputLength > 1) {
            var newInputArray = [] as any;
            this.state.data.forEach((inputState: any) => {
                if (inputState === input) {
                    listArray.splice(arrTarget, 1);                   
                    input.config.order = listArray.toString();
                    newInputArray.push(input)
                }
                else {
                    newInputArray.push(inputState)
                }
            })
            this.setState({ data: newInputArray })
            //Save this new list to API
            updateList(input);
        }
    }
    onChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<any>, input: any, name: string) {
        e.persist();
        if (e.target.refreshTimer) {
            clearTimeout(e.target.refreshTimer);
        }
        e.target.refreshTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.delaySaveOfList(e, input, name)
        }, 1000);
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Inputs</h1>
                {this.state.data.map((input: any) => (

                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <p className="card-text">Inputs:</p>
                            {this.generateInput(input).map((name: any, index: number) => (
                                <>
                                    <input id="ListInput" type="text" defaultValue={name} name={index.toString()} key={index} onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, input, name) }} />
                                    <br />
                                </>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I will say, once I refresh the page, the order of the inputs is correct, as it pulls data from the API again, so I assume I'm doing something wrong with the state data.

Comment: you're probably mutating the state, that's why you see an inconsistent layout in the ui

Comment: the code is a bit difficult to follow, so far I could spot this `input.config.order = listArray.toString();` here you're mutating the state: you iterate over the state in the render function, passing the input to `delaySaveOfList` and then reassign a property of an object, which is the same object reference that's in your state

Comment: @shidoro Yes, sorry I know the code is messy. I understand what you're getting at with the state mutation, but I don't think that 'input' is part of the state, right?  'input' is being passed as a parameter in the delaySaveOfList.

Comment: It is indeed the very same, as objects in javascript are passed by reference and not by value. Try this on your devtool: `const obj = {}; function myFn(input) { input.a = 'input was modified' }; myFn(obj); console.log(obj);`

Comment: @shidoro I see.. In that case how do I get around my current state mutation? Currently I can't see another way of doing this..